# On select Input type="file" change input type "text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML form with input type=text and input type=file (my case Title and File), I wanna when someone select file, to change value of Title. I tried with Javascript but I am not even close to the solution.

Comment: What did you try? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, a `.change()` event will do the trick:

```
<input type="text" id="title"/>
<input type="file" id="file"/> 

$("#file").change(function() {
    $("#title").val("Changed!");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FkJss/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$("input:file").change(function () {
    $("#idtexbox").val('DesiredValue');

    $("input:file").val("");//clear file input value
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FkJss/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery.change():

```
$(file_selector).change(function (){
  $(title_selector).val(value_to_change);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any jQuery, do this:

```
document.getElementByID("file").onchange(function(){
    document.getElementByID("title").value("Changed!");
});
```

Comment: There is no `value()` method on input elements.  Furthermore, this is not how you register a "change" handler (or any event handler for that matter) using plain 'ole javascript.  Also, the function should be `getElementById`.